# Waveform fails to connect to UHD_USRP device when launched in domain manager from IDE

Tags: redhawksdr

I have created a waveform in the REDHAWKSDR IDE (Version 2.0.2) comprising a USRP_UHD device and a DataConverter. I followed carefully Section 7.2 "Associating a Waveform with an FEI Device" in the manual and used the "Use Frontend Tuner Device" artifact to define a device port and connection to the DataConverter. The port and connection render on the diagram. I saved the waveform and exported it to SDR.

I created a USRP node, added the UHD_USRP device to the node, and set the IP address. I can launch the node's DeviceManager, allocate the UHD_USRP frontend tuner manually, and confirm data flow on a NextMidas plot.

When I launch the waveform in the REDHAWK_DEV domain manager, the UHD_USRP device in waveform diagram is missing port and connection. The REDHAWK Explorer shows that the UHD_USRP device is allocated but the output port shows an unknown "Connection_1" and the DataConverter input port shows no connection. I recreated the connection manually using the "Connect" menu,  but I get no data flow.

This basic USRP connection should be very simple, but I find no useful discussion in this forum or elsewhere. One observation: I can get the connection in python with the following commands:

> > > from ossie.utils import sb
> > >
> > > import frontend
> > >
> > > sb.catalog(objType='devices')
> > >
> > > usrp = sb.launch('rh.USRP_UHD')
> > >
> > > usrp.target_device.ip_address = '192.168.10.2'
> > >
> > > alloc = frontend.createTunerAllocation("RX_DIGITIZER",
> > >       allocation_id="testing", center_frequency=925.0e6, sample_rate=20.0e6, sample_rate_tolerance=20.0)
> > >
> > > usrp.allocateCapacity(alloc)
> > >
> > > alloc1 = frontend.createTunerListenerAllocation("testing", "listener1")
> > >
> > > usrp.allocateCapacity(alloc1)
> > >
> > > converter = sb.launch('rh.DataConverter')
> > >
> > > converter.maxTransferSize = 262144
> > >
> > > usrp.connect(converter, usesPortName="dataShort_out", providesPortName="dataShort", connectionId='listener1')
> > >
> > > plot2 = sb.RasterPSD(nfft=8192, frameSize=8192)
> > >
> > > converter.connect(plot2, usesPortName="dataFloat_out", providesPortName="FloatIn")
> > >
> > > sb.start()

Comment: Could you provide the guide you followed?

Comment: An observation: you're creating an allocation with ID "testing", then creating a listener with ID "listener1"  but in this simple example, the listener is unnecessary. You could have simply connected the USRP_UHD to the DataConverter using the allocation ID "testing"  as the connection ID. My point being, is the connection ID in your waveform between the two entities the same as the allocation ID, or is it the default of "Connection_1"? If it's the default, change it to the allocation ID and data should flow

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on old notes so it may not work. We do most of our connections dynamically through python these days. I didn't have a USRP on hand to test with.

I generated a quick waveform the way you described and the following XML was generated in the .sad.xml file:

```
<connections>
    <connectinterface id="connection_1">
        <usesport>
            <usesidentifier>dataShort_out</usesidentifier>
            <deviceusedbyapplication usesrefid="rh.USRP_UHD_1"/>
        </usesport>
        <providesport>
            <providesidentifier>dataShort</providesidentifier>
            <componentinstantiationref refid="DataConverter_1"/>
        </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
</connections>
<usesdevicedependencies>
    <usesdevice id="rh.USRP_UHD_1">
         <propertyref refid="DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d" value="FRONTEND::TUNER"/>
         <propertyref refid="DCE:0f99b2e4-9903-4631-9846-ff349d18ecfb" value="USRP"/>
         <structref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation">
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::tuner_type" value="RX_DIGITIZER"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id" value="devuser:6e463f2c-fe8f-4997-98e9-39bf1364c861"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::center_frequency" value="9.0E8"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth" value="0.0"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth_tolerance" value="20.0"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate" value="0.0"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate_tolerance" value="20.0"/>
             <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::device_control" value="true"/>
            <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::group_id" value=""/>
            <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::rf_flow_id" value=""/>
        </structref>
    </usesdevice>
</usesdevicedependencies>
```

The id in the connectinterface element used to be the same as the allocation_id of the device.

```
<connectinterface id="connection_1">
```

should be

```
<connectinterface id="devuser:6e463f2c-fe8f-4997-98e9-39bf1364c861">
```

in the generated code above instead of "connection_1". Replace the "devuser:6e463f2c-fe8f-4997-98e9-39bf1364c861" string with whatever was generated for your allocation.

Comment: Adding the <connectinterface id> tag to the              <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id" value="devuser:6e463f2c-fe8f-4997-98e9-39bf1364c861"/>

Comment: I confirm this solution: In the .sad.xml file, manually add the <connectinterface id> tag to the <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id" or viz-versa.  It would be nice to see this subtlety written in the REDHAWK documentation. And thank you.

Comment: Addition: I did notice a red banner that appears in the Waveform Editor under the Properties tab: "The required feature 'refId' of 'Device Used By Application' must be set", however, this language makes no sense to me, nor does it provide instructions about how to set what, where.

Comment: What's the final form? I'm having issues with the basic tutorial. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277461/what-causes-the-required-feature-refid-of-device-used-by-application-must