# What causes "The required feature ' refId' of 'Device Used By Application' must be set"

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm using REDHAWK 2.0.4 on CentOS 7

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SttCsAIQtSA
At 11:14 they add a device dependency to the xml file:

```
<usesdevicedependencies>
  <usesdevice id="device_connection">
    <propertyref refid="DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d"
                 value="chirp"/>
  </usesdevice>
<usesdevicedependencies>
```

And this

```
<connectinterface id="device_connection_1">
  <usesport>
    <usesidentifier>dataFloat_out</usesidentifier>
    <deviceusedbyapplication usesrefid="device_connection"/>
  </usesport>
  <providesport>
    <providesidentifier>dataFloat_In</providesidentifier>
    <componentinstationref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_1"/>
  </providesport>
</connectinterface>
```

When I do the same thing, I'm given the error from the title:

```
The required feature ' refId' of 'Device Used By Application' must be set
```

I thought "DeviceUsedByApplication" used "usesrefid", maybe this error is caused by something else?

Comment: What version of REDHAWK are you using?  Is a device manager running in your Domain with a Device whose device_kind property (per that refid above) is set to "chirp"?

Comment: 2.0.4 Yes, and more interestingly this error/warning doesn't actually matter since my waveform works properly. I just need to press "Yes" twice when it complains to me about it.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a change that came out after I posted the updated versions of the tutorials last year.  Chances are the developers tweaked the definition so that the deviceusedbyapplication requires the refid tag to fit in with the schema, but the usesrefid is the actual one being employed by the framework when preparing to launch the waveform.  In essence it would throw an error that the schema check failed, or something along those lines, but still works, as you observed. (Just my guess, not having dug into it yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got message from the developer and they said that the issue has been confirmed in 2.0.4.

```
Just to confirm, the issue that you experienced in 2.0.4 has actually been
there a while, but it seems like it's now getting checked. Adding the refid to 
the devicesusedbyapplication will get rid of the message, but as you 
experienced, it has no bearing on whether or not it breaks anything. With any 
luck it'll be fixed soon. Until then though, it can be ignored or mitigated as you did.﻿
```

Comment: Well, I'm not one of the developers, just one of the users.  Thanks for letting us know about this issue.

Comment: @Thomas Can you please look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592967/error-registering-gpp-device-on-a-domain

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @0xbaadf00d.  It looks like you all seem to have resolved this to not having the environment variables configured prior to running the domain.  Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I got it working, don't know about the other guy though. I'm having more difficulties though, Debugging doesn't seem to work. Running a component in release mode in sandbox works, but debug mode causes instant crash. More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980705/redhawk-component-debugging

Answer (score 2):

The error being reported by the IDE is actually incorrect. This is a bug that was fixed in the recent 2.0.5 release. See the release notes (https://github.com/redhawksdr/redhawk/releases/tag/2.0.5):

> Adding a FrontEnd Uses Device to a Waveform no longer causes an error when saving the Waveform

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592967/error-registering-gpp-device-on-a-domain